# Problems getting a development certificate for iOS 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Developer Program - can't get a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658859/ios-developer-program-cant-get-a-certificate)

So I am trying to develop an iDevice application, and I can't seem to get a development certificate.  I am running XCode 4.3.1 and Mac OS X 10.7.3 and iOS 5.1.

First, I've tried going to the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and using the "Development Provisioning Assistant."  When I go through that (using both Chrome and Safari), when I upload the CSR (generated by going to Keychain Access => Certificate Assistant => Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority and then enter my Apple ID email, name), it hangs with ["We were unable to generate your Provisioning Profile. Please try again or visit the Provisioning section of the Provisioning Portal."](http://twitpic.com/8v4oyn)

So, then I figured I'd try going to the [iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Development](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action).  I download the WWDR intermediate certificate and double click on it, which I think "installs" it.  At least, it appears in my Keychain as "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"  Then I hit "Request Certificate" (and note that it directs me with "Important: Xcode is the preferred method for requesting and automatically installing this certificate. Before proceeding, read [Tools Workflow Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959)." -- this will be important later).  I follow the directions, creating a CSR, which I then upload on that page.  When I hit "Submit" I'm brought back to my Current Development Certificates, which excitingly, now reads ["Pending Issuance."](http://twitpic.com/8v4w9s)  Lots of places on the rest of the internet [say to just refresh the page](http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/iphone/howto-iphone-application-development-environment) and supposedly I should be done.  Except when I refresh, it just says I don't have any valid development certificates and presents me with [the first view](http://twitpic.com/8v4xcu), from which I can request a certificate.

So, what about that link to the iOS Application Development Workflows?  When you check that out and start to read through it, it says that "If you are a team administrator or the team agent, provision your device for generic development. Xcode installs your development certificate in your keychain (if it’s not there already), and installs the team provisioning profile on your device."  I don't have a team--I'm an individual--but when I go to XCode to provision the device, I go to the Organizer > LIBRARY > Provisioning Profiles > Refresh.  Then, it asks me to sign in with my Apple ID, tells me "No iOS Development Certificate Found" and offers to "Submit Request" on my behalf!  Hurray?  Then I see it says "Submitting CSR . . . Waiting for CSR Approval" and it hangs there for awhile. . .then it says, "Certificate Requested :: A certificate request has been submitted on your behalf, but has not yet been approved. An Agent or Admin must approve this request before you can download your certificate."  That's super cool, right?

Except there's nowhere I can go to approve that request, and if I go to my [Certificate History](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/certificateHistory.action) I see a long, long history of Errors.  Except they're not informative at all, because it just says Error.

So at this point, I've spent ~8h trying to fix this.  I've tried provisioning an iPad, iPhone, resetting my keychain, setting up XCode on a separate account, and of course updating and upgrading all the software.

Let me know if I've left anything out.

Comment: Someone else is having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9658859/535632

Comment: Are you a paid member of the iOS developer program? Having Xcode will allow you to write iOS apps and test them on the Simulator. But to get provisioning certificates (which are tied to your log on ID) you have to be a paid member.

Comment: Yes, I am.  I can verify this by going to Member Center > Your Account and there is no "Join Today" next to iOS Developer Program.

Comment: Awesome; thanks for pointing that out.  Hope it's resolved soon--

Comment: Please vote/flag to close the question as a duplicate instead of putting a banner at the top of your question that points to another question.